# Replicate a column in a one-line CSV file

Tags: text-processing, python, csv

I have a file that consists of a single line:

```
a,x,b,c,d,e
```

I want to convert this into

```
a,x,b,x,c,x,d,x,e,x
```

Which is the easiest way to achieve this? A solution based on Python will be most helpful

Also supposing that this file is a csv file will python make the work easier?

Comment: I see the tag python ? is it relevant or do you need az pythononly solution, because you better mention it expicitly.

Comment: A pythonly solution will help but is not a necessary requirement

Comment: then you should [edit] your question to make it more obvious, becaus e there is pythonly solution but without asking you will fall with good old GNU tool :)

Comment: Given the various interpretations in the received answers, you should specify whether you want to insert literal “x” or the value of the 2nd field.

Comment: I want the value of second field

Comment: Why is this a Unix & Linux question and not a StackOverflow question?

Comment: @kojiro why this quesiton not on hold as unclear ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
    parts = line.split(',')
    glue = parts.pop(1)
    print(',{0},'.format(glue).join(parts) + ',' + glue)
```

Comment: great reuse of input :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
echo 'a,x,b,c,d,e' | sed 's/,\([^x]\)/,\1,x/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/,x,/,/g;s/[^,]*/&,x/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your data is not actually what you show and instead, you want to repeat the 2nd column of a csv file, whatever that column may be, not only if it is an `x`. If so, these should work:

```
$ echo "a,x,b,c,d,e" | 
    perl -lpe 's/^(.+?),([^,]+)/$1/; $n=$2; s/([^,]+)/$1,$n/g; '
a,x,b,x,c,x,d,x,e,x
```

And in `awk`:

```
$ echo "a,x,b,c,d,e" | 
    awk -F, '{k=$1","$2","$3; for(i=4;i<=NF; i++){k=k","$2","$(i)} 
              print k","$2}'
a,x,b,x,c,x,d,x,e,x
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl way:

```
echo "a,x,b,c,d,e" |
 perl -lpe '@_= map { $_ => "x" } grep !/x/, split /,/,;$_=join ",",@_;'
a,x,b,x,c,x,d,x,e,x
```